# The first button I create is overlapped by the second button

Tags: java, android

Basically, the first button is generated but then the second button is placed on top of it, then after the second button they begin to be sorted one under the other and I'm not sure why I need the second button to be placed under the first as well I can't have the second button overlap it, any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Created a button # " + i + "!");
            Button button = new Button(this);
            button.setId(i);

            //Define the height and width of the button.
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonDetails = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, //Width
                    200 //Height
            );

            if (i > 0) { //If it isn't the first button, then...
                //Place it below the previous button.
                buttonDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, i - 1);
            }

            //Add the button text.
            button.setText(something[i]);

            //Center the button horizontally.
            buttonDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

            //Generate a button for the class.
            layout.addView(button, buttonDetails);
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="Menu">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: simple solution to your problem, if you create these button inside a LinearLayout whose orientaion set to Vertical this issue will not come.

Comment: use linear layout/table layout for this.

Comment: this code should work without any modifications, can you add more info, or add your Relative layout xml part

Comment: @AtefHares I added my XML.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/RelativeLayout.java#974), adding a rule with a subject of 0 will cause it to be ignored during layout. This is the case for your second `Button`. In general, it's best to use static ids (e.g. `R.id.some_id`) instead of ones you create yourself. If you must use ids you generate, `View.generateViewId()` is very useful, but it's limited to API 17+. If you need to support older API's it's simple enough to [copy the method](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#21949).

As others have mentioned, a vertically-oriented `LinearLayout` will accomplish what you're trying to do with a lot less manual work.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you cannot use 0 as id. Start with 1. It will work fine. Make code as given below

```
for (int i = 1; i <= classes.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Created a button # " + i + "!");
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setId(i);

        //Define the height and width of the button.
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonDetails = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, //Width
                200 //Height
        );

        if (i > 1) { //If it isn't the first button, then...
            //Place it below the previous button.
            buttonDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, i - 1);
        }

        //Add the button text.
        button.setText(something[i-1]);

        //Center the button horizontally.
        buttonDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        //Generate a button for the class.
        layout.addView(button, buttonDetails);
   }
```

Comment: I didn't see the "<=" change, I actually figured it out myself then went back to look and realized what you did haha, thanks brother!

Answer (score -1):

```
layout.addView(button, buttonDetails);<br/>
```

which layout is this ?
If its LinearLayout with orientation vertical then it won't overlap, also in such case you don't need to mention about RelativeLayout.BELOW part.